# How do we check if an item exists in selectoption

Tags: apex

I am trying to avoid having duplicate selectoptions which are populated in apex.
There are couple of places from which the selectoptions are getting populated and there is a possibility of getting duplicate values. I am currently storing the selectoptions related to a target group within a map

```
for(Group_Members__c gm : [SELECT name,Product_Target_Group__c FROM Group_Members__c WHERE Product_Target_Group__c IN :TGroupsSet])
        {

            if(ProductTargetGroupMap.containsKey(gm.Product_Target_Group__c) && ProductTargetGroupMap.get(gm.Product_Target_Group__c) != null)
            {
                TargetingOptions = ProductTargetGroupMap.get(gm.Product_Target_Group__c);

                TargetingOptions.add(new Selectoption(gm.name,gm.name));
                ProductTargetGroupMap.put(gm.Product_Target_Group__c, TargetingOptions.clone());
            }
            else
            {
                TargetingOptions.add(new Selectoption(gm.name,gm.name));
                ProductTargetGroupMap.put(gm.Product_Target_Group__c, TargetingOptions.clone());
            }
        }
```

What is the best way to check if there is an existing selectoption value?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i managed to do it by moving the list into a set and adding the new selectoption value and then moving it from set back to List.

```
for(Group_Members__c gm : [SELECT name,Product_Target_Group__c FROM Group_Members__c WHERE Product_Target_Group__c IN :TGroupsSet])
        {

            if(ProductTargetGroupMap.containsKey(gm.Product_Target_Group__c) && ProductTargetGroupMap.get(gm.Product_Target_Group__c) != null)
            {
                TargetingOptions = ProductTargetGroupMap.get(gm.Product_Target_Group__c);

                TargetingOptions.add(new Selectoption(gm.name,gm.name));
                TargetingOptionsSet.addAll(TargetingOptions);
                TargetingOptionsDup.clear();
                TargetingOptionsDup.addAll(TargetingOptionsSet);
                ProductTargetGroupMap.put(gm.Product_Target_Group__c, TargetingOptionsDup.clone());
            }
            else
            {
                TargetingOptions.add(new Selectoption(gm.name,gm.name));
                ProductTargetGroupMap.put(gm.Product_Target_Group__c, TargetingOptions.clone());
            }
        }
```